# kotlin Coroutine multiple launch

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

How to make multiple launch like multiple thread in kotlin

I want to make that `first` `second` are working at the same time forever!!

Like this code...

```
runBlocking {

    // first
    launch{
      first()
    }

    // second
    launch{
       second()
    }
}


suspend fun first(){
    // do something 
    delay(1000L)

    // Recursive call
    first() 
}

suspend fun second(){
    // do something 
    delay(1000L)

    // Recursive call
    second() 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example code would work already, if it is the only running code in your application. If you need those two methods running in parallel to your application, wrap them in `GlobalScope.launch`:

```
GlobalScope.launch {

   launch { first() }
   launch { second() }
}
```

This will run forever until canceled and/or an exception inside is thrown. If you don't require too many resources inside a coroutine and release them properly when used, you should never have a problem with StackOverFlow.

---

In addition to recursive code: try to make a loop instead as it is suggested in the comments.

Comment: I actually got it wrong in the comment, so I deleted it. Using recursion is a good solution because of the tail call optimization. Also I found out that to make it work it is necessary to use `delay()` or `yield()`, so thank you.

Comment: You don't get tail recursion automatically in Kotlin, you must declare your function  as `tailrec`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  I've tested the code above and the OP's code with the VisualVM and observed a memory leak of `DispatchedContinuation`, `first$1`, `second$1` objects. If I use `delay(0)` or `yield()` instead of `delay(1000L)` I get OutOfMemoryError soon after start. After I added the `tailrec` keyword to the functions, there was no memory leak.

Comment: @vitalyros Thanks for investigation

Answer (score 1):

You can implement infinite execution with cycles

```
runBlocking {
    launch { while(true) first() }
    launch { while(true) second() }
}

suspend fun first(){
    // do something 
    delay(1000L)
}

suspend fun second(){
    // do something 
    delay(1000L)
}
```